# Combining four methods into one

Tags: java, methods

How can I replace four methods with one that will update the variable "str" to match the operators "+ - / *" with "ADD, SUB, DIV or MULT"? When It runs through the case statements, I am trying to figure out how to get the case statement to recognize the operator that was chosen via the scanner input and match it to its respective descriptor string.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Testor4 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s1 = getInput("Enter a number: ");
    String s2 = getInput("Enter second number");
    String op = getInput("Enter operator: + - / * ");
    double result = 0;
    String str = " You chose to";
    try{
        switch(op){
        case "+": str += getOpNameAdd(str); result = getSum(s1,s2); break;
        case "-": str += getOpNameSub(str); result = getSub(s1,s2); break;
        case "/": str += getOpNameDiv(str); result = getDiv(s1,s2); break;
        case "*": str += getOpNameMult(str); result = getMult(s1,s2); break;
        default: System.out.println("not an operator."); return;
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    System.out.printf("%s%s%.2f","Result is: ",str,result);
    }
    private static double getSum(String s1, String s2){
    double d1 = Double.parseDouble(s1);
    double d2 = Double.parseDouble(s2);
    return d1 + d2;
    }
    private static double getSub(String s1, String s2){
    double d1 = Double.parseDouble(s1);
    double d2 = Double.parseDouble(s2);
    return d1 - d2;
    }
    private static double getDiv(String s1, String s2){
    double d1 = Double.parseDouble(s1);
    double d2 = Double.parseDouble(s2);
    return d1 / d2;
    }
    private static double getMult(String s1, String s2){
    double d1 = Double.parseDouble(s1);
    double d2 = Double.parseDouble(s2);
    return d1 * d2;
    }
    public static String getOpNameAdd(String str){
    return str = " ADD!";
    }
    public static String getOpNameSub(String str){  
    return str = " Subtract!";
    }
    public static String getOpNameDiv(String str){  
    return str = " Divide!";
    }
    public static String getOpNameMult(String str){ 
    return str = " Multiply!";
    }
    public static String getInput(String prompt){
    System.out.println(prompt);
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    return sc.nextLine();
    }
    }
```

Comment: What did you see when you ran your code through a debugger?

Comment: WHAT? it works fine. There is no problem with it that requires debugging. Did you try running it and it failed? The question is how do I combine the four methods at the bottom that do one specific thing and return the words "ADD< SUB,,, etc." It seems to me there must be a way to run an if then statement or at it to the getSum(), getSub, methods, without having to create al the extra code.

Comment: No, I didn't, but you said "I am trying to figure out how to get the case statement to recognize the operator" which makes it sound like you're having trouble with that part.

Comment: Why not have a method `getOpName`, pass it `op`, and in the method have a `switch...case` that returns the appropriate string? Not sure if it's what you're looking for, as it's just a redundency of `switch...case`s, so that any modification to the operators would have to be done in 2 places.

Comment: @ AntonH, cane you give an example? When I do this it requires that I set op to null or " ", which in the end is about the same amount of code. So I am trying to consolidate.

Comment: OP, you might look into Java Enums.

Comment: An elegant approach is to use a Calculator Interface (methods = getOpName() and calculate()).  Then you create a concrete instance for each new operator, and the code for each operator is centralized in the class

Comment: it's funny because I'd rather have the original code instead of the accepted answer, replacing the function call with the actual string. I have a pet peeve with functions that always return the same thing, since it can be replaced with a constant defined at the start of the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Testor4 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s1 = getInput("Enter a number: ");
    String s2 = getInput("Enter second number");
    String op = getInput("Enter operator: + - / * ");
    double result = 0;
    String str = " You chose to";
    try {
        switch (op) {
        case "+":
            str += getOpName(op);
            result = getSum(s1, s2);
            break;
        case "-":
            str += getOpName(op);
            result = getSub(s1, s2);
            break;
        case "/":
            str += getOpName(op);
            result = getDiv(s1, s2);
            break;
        case "*":
            str += getOpName(op);
            result = getMult(s1, s2);
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("not an operator.");
            return;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    System.out.printf("%s%s%.2f", "Result is: ", str, result);
}

private static double getSum(String s1, String s2) {
    double d1 = Double.parseDouble(s1);
    double d2 = Double.parseDouble(s2);
    return d1 + d2;
}

private static double getSub(String s1, String s2) {
    double d1 = Double.parseDouble(s1);
    double d2 = Double.parseDouble(s2);
    return d1 - d2;
}

private static double getDiv(String s1, String s2) {
    double d1 = Double.parseDouble(s1);
    double d2 = Double.parseDouble(s2);
    return d1 / d2;
}

private static double getMult(String s1, String s2) {
    double d1 = Double.parseDouble(s1);
    double d2 = Double.parseDouble(s2);
    return d1 * d2;
}

public static String getOpName(String op) {
    String opName = "not an operator.";
    switch (op) {
    case "+":
        opName = " ADD!";
        break;
    case "-":
        opName = " Subtract!";
        break;
    case "/":
        opName = " Divide!";
        break;
    case "*":
        opName = " Multiply!";
        break;
    }
    return opName;
}

public static String getInput(String prompt) {
    System.out.println(prompt);
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    return sc.nextLine();
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

Why not do this?

```
try{
    switch(op){
    case "+": str += " ADD!"; result = getSum(s1,s2); break;
    case "-": str += " Subtract!"; result = getSub(s1,s2); break;
    case "/": str += " Divide!"; result = getDiv(s1,s2); break;
    case "*": str += " Multiply!"; result = getMult(s1,s2); break;
    default: System.out.println("not an operator."); return;
    }
}catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

If the strings will be reused elsewhere you may also make it a string constant:

```
public static final String OpNameAdd = " ADD!";
```

Answer (score 1):

I would begin by writing an `enum` (such as `Operation` here) to encapsulate the behaviour, the name and the symbol(s). Something like,

```
enum Operation {
    ADD("+", "Addition"), SUBTRACT("-", "Subtraction"), //
    MULTIPLY("*", "Multiplication"), DIVIDE("/", "Division");
    String operSymbol;
    String operName;

    Operation(String operSymbol, String operName) {
        this.operSymbol = operSymbol;
        this.operName = operName;
    }

    String getName() {
        return operName;
    }

    String getSymbol() {
        return operSymbol;
    }

    public static Operation fromString(String str) {
        if (str != null) {
            str = str.trim();
            if (!str.isEmpty()) {
                for (Operation o : Operation.values()) {
                    if (str.equals(o.getSymbol())) {
                        return o;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public double performOperation(String s1, String s2) {
        Double d1 = Double.parseDouble(s1);
        Double d2 = Double.parseDouble(s2);
        switch (this) {
        case SUBTRACT:
            return d1 - d2;
        case MULTIPLY:
            return d1 * d2;
        case DIVIDE:
            return d1 / d2;
        case ADD:
        default:
            return d1 + d2;
        }
    }
}
```

Please don't open a new scanner for each prompt. I would pass it into the method. Like,

```
public static String getInput(Scanner sc, String prompt) {
    System.out.println(prompt);
    return sc.nextLine();
}
```

Then your `main` method is very simple, you get the required input and invoke methods on an `Operation` like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s1 = getInput(sc, "Enter a number: ");
    String s2 = getInput(sc, "Enter second number");
    String op = getInput(sc, "Enter operator: + - / * ");
    try {
        Operation oper = Operation.fromString(op);
        if (op != null) {
            double result = oper.performOperation(s1, s2);
            System.out.printf("%s %s %s = %.2f (%s)%n", s1, //
                    oper.getSymbol(), s2, result, oper.getName());
        } else {
            System.out.println("not an operator.");
            return;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd do it.  Start with an interface:

```
package cruft.arithmetic;

/**
 * BinaryOperation is the interface for binary arithmetic operations +, -, *, /
 * Created by Michael
 * Creation date 1/11/2016.
 * @link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34734228/combining-four-methods-into-one
 */
public interface BinaryOperation<T>  {

    T execute(T argument1, T argument2);
}
```

Implementation for addition:

```
package cruft.arithmetic;

/**
 * Addition implementation for BinaryOperation
 * Created by Michael
 * Creation date 1/11/2016.
 * @link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34734228/combining-four-methods-into-one
 */
public class AddOperation implements BinaryOperation<Double> {

    @Override
    public Double execute(Double argument1, Double argument2) {
        return argument1 + argument2;
    }
}
```

Here's the Tester:

```
package cruft.arithmetic;

/**
 * I think the class name is misspelled: "Tester".
 * Created by Michael
 * Creation date 1/11/2016.
 * @link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34734228/combining-four-methods-into-one
 */

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Tester {

    private static final Map<String, BinaryOperation<Double>> OPERATIONS = new HashMap<String, BinaryOperation<Double>>() {{
        put("+", new AddOperation());
    }};
    private static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BinaryOperation<Double> operator = null;
        do {
            try {
                String arg1 = getInput("1st argument    : ");
                String arg2 = getInput("2nd argument    : ");
                String oper = getInput("operator + - * /: ");
                operator = OPERATIONS.get(oper);
                if (operator != null) {
                    double x = Double.parseDouble(arg1);
                    double y = Double.parseDouble(arg2);
                    double z = operator.execute(x, y);
                    System.out.println(String.format("%-10.4f %s %-10.4f = %-10.4f", x, oper, y, z));
                } else {
                    System.out.println(String.format("No such operator '%s'", oper));
                }
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } while (operator != null);
    }

    public static String getInput(String prompt) {
        System.out.print(prompt);
        return sc.nextLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With one method, and more simple, you could read one input and  process a string "prefix+suffix" where + stands for all possible operations,
with something like  [static int    indexOfAny(String str, char[] searchChars)](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html)
 get the substrings prefix, suffix , then switch(op) according to operator.